# Website hosted on Dropbox not accessing file in Dropbox API app

Tags: jquery, html, dropbox

I am using dropbox to host a website(intended to be a web app) that does a basic task: uses JQuery to fetch the contents of a text file that is located in Dropbox and displays it in a paragraph. The text file is located in a Dropbox API application. When I load my code locally on my mac, it works fine:
[Image of local results](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9v94jj9z3n4uk1/local.png?dl=1).

But when I try it using the HTML file on Dropbox I get this:
[Image of server results](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zm4o8t37fooqs4m/server.png?dl=1)

My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"/>

    <title>Fetch</title>
    <style>

    body {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: #222;
        font-family: -apple-system-font;
        font-size: 17px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #header h1 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #header h1 a {
        background-color: #5BBF60;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        font-family: -apple-system-font;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #222;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 0;
        padding-top: 20;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
    p {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #rbutton {
        text-align: center;
        color: 0B60FF;
    }
    </style>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        document.ontouchstart=document.onmousedown=preventer;
        function preventer(e){    
        if(!e){e=window.event;}
        e.preventDefault();
    }  
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("https://dropboxapitextfilelink", function(data) {
                $("#status").html(data);
        });
        var dt = new Date();
        var time = "Last updated on: " + dt.toUTCString();
        $("#updated").html(time);
        setInterval(function(){
            $.get("https://dropboxapitextfilelink", function(data) {
                $("#status").html(data);
            });
            dt = new Date();
            time = "Last updated on: " + dt.toUTCString();
            $("#updated").html(time);
        }, 3000);
        $("p").click(function(){
            $.get("https://dropboxapitextfilelink", function(data) {
                $("#status").html(data);
            });
            dt = new Date();
            time = "Last updated on: " + dt.toUTCString();
            $("#updated").html(time);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1><a>Fetch</a></h1>
    </div>
    <p id="status"></p>
    <div id="rbutton">
        <p id="refresh">Refresh</p>
    </div>
    <p id="updated"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried using BitBucket to host the static website and put the code in JSFiddle, but the text string does not show up. It appears only on my Mac's web browser. Also, I cannot use a different service to have the text file, I am using a service that only lets me upload to a Dropbox API app.

Thanks

**EDIT:** Added images

Comment: Is your file available with the URL you use in your code without further authentication? Is your html file and your dropbox required file accessed with the same domain name?

Comment: What error or issue are you seeing?

Comment: @JonatanCloutier On a computer that I am not logged in on, I can use the link and successfully download the file.

Comment: @smarx Sorry about that, I forgot to upload the images

Comment: You've shown the output, but you haven't shown what error (if any) you're receiving. Look in your browser's console for errors... there's some response from the server when you do your `$.get(...)`, and that response will presumably tell you the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that. I get 2 errors ever time I try to fetch it: "[Error] Failed to load resource: Cannot make any requests from null. (file.txt, line 0)." and "[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://dropboxfilelink. Cannot make any requests from null. (index.html, line 0)"

Comment: You could try debugging in your browser, you clearly have a value that is null in your get maybe the URL if it's a variable you use